# Unable to get the img src from the external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Html page where I have a image tag,I want to display an image which I have deployed in an external webApplication.When I browse that link in a browser it is working but when i add that link into an img src its not working

```
<img id="empPic" alt="" src="http://xyz/emp/displayImage.jsp?empId=7" width="90px" height="100px" style="border-radius: 12px;">
```

Comment: Please provide external web Application link

Comment: You must have used some authentication mechanism which prevents unauthorized access.

Answer (score 0):

```
src="http://xyz/emp/displayImage.jsp?empId=7"
```

The Serversscript have to give you the data of image and not a reference to the image.

If the jsp gives you only a reference, you have to received the reference first and set it in the src-attribute